# How to Use Join Function TO display Multiple values of one Field in crystal Reports 2008

Tags: join, crystal-reports-2008, formula-editor

I'm trying to Display the Multiple Values of One Database field ("{Customers.Name}"). I was tried to using Join function Like

```
Join({Customers.Name},","); 
or 
Stringvar array name:={Customers.Name};
for i :=1 to count(name)
(
join(name[i],",");
);![enter image description here][1]
```

These two codes not woriking because of following one error 
"String array Requried for Join function"
Please Help Me to Solve this

Comment: you need to provide a string array and not string... understand the difference between both and write your code.

Comment: im using String Array only ... please see my code once again..

I was used follwoing code for array in above

**Stringvar Array name:={Customers.Name};**

Comment: how does the data in database field customer.name looks like

Comment: <customers.Name> Tag name from XML. Its Contains Following Values
<customers Name>Hari</customers Name>
<customers Name>Ravi</customers Name>
<customers Name>Ram</customers Name>

Answer (score 1):

It seems `{Customers.Name}` consist a string, foreach detail section gets values one by by one from XML. If You try to show all names comma separeted, you buld it in detail section, and show it in a group or page footer.

to do this, in group / page header initialize your variable:

```
Shared StringVar names := "";
```

in detail:

```
Shared StringVar names;
names := names & ", " & {Customers.Name};
```

in group / page footer in a print variable:

```
Shared StringVar names;
names
```